# Targeting Occurrence

Tags: php, arrays, string, count

I have a simple non-associative array with a few thousand values.
The values are strings of 1-10 words.

I need to find the 3-4 consecutive word string that has the most "hits" in the array.

This is alphanumeric and case-insensitive.

A hit could be:

Any single word of the string occurs within an item of the array.
Any set of multiple consecutive words occur within an item of the array.

So, an example:

```
$database = array(
  0 => 'the dogs whisperer',
  1 => 'I am a whisperer',
  2 => 'dogs are often hairy',
  3 => 'dogs',
  4 => 'are you a dogs whisperer'
  5 => 'dogs can be manipulated by a whisperer');
```

The three word string "the dogs whisperer" would get the following hits:

"the dogs whisperer" in "the dogs whisperer"

"dogs whisperer" in "the dogs whisperer"

"the dogs" in "the dogs whisperer"

"the" in "the dogs whisperer"

"dogs" in "the dogs whisperer"

"whisperer in "the dogs whisperer"

"whisperer" in "I am a whisperer"

"dogs" in "dogs are often hairy"

"dogs" in "dogs"

"dogs whisperer" in "are you a dogs whisperer"

"dogs" in "are you a dogs whisperer"

"whisperer" in "are you a dogs whisperer"

"dogs" in "dogs can be manipulated by a whisperer"

"whisperer" in "dogs can be manipulated by a whisperer"

In order for a multi word string to get a hit, the words must be consecutive.  i.e. "dogs whisperer" is NOT a hit on "dogs can be manipulated by a whisperer.

Words must also be in order. i.e "dogs whisperer" is NOT a hit in the value "whisperer dogs".

I have a good grasp of the different array functions, I just can't get it all put together.  I have tried extracting all possible sets of strings by exploding by word and recombining, then using strpos!==FALSE to look for hits.  I end up with a gargantuan matrix that I just can't get the output from that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for. I'm sure there's a lot you can optimize but i think this will point you in the right direction.

HTH, Andy

```
<?php
  $database = array(
  0 => 'the dogs whisperer',
  1 => 'I am a whisperer',
  2 => 'dogs are often hairy',
  3 => 'dogs',
  4 => 'are you a dogs whisperer',
  5 => 'dogs can be manipulated by a whisperer');

  function CreateSubsets($sstr)
  {
    $subsets = array();

    $tokens = explode(" ", $sstr);
    $count = count($tokens);

    for ($i = $count; $i > 0; $i--) 
    {
      for ($j = 0; $j + $i <= $count; $j++)
      {
        $subsets[] = implode(" ", array_slice($tokens, $j, $i));
      }      
    } 

    return $subsets;   
  }

  function SearchOccurrences($database, $subsets)
  {
    $resultAry = array();

    for ($subIdx = 0; $subIdx < count($subsets); $subIdx++) 
    {
      $occurrences = array();
      for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($database); $idx++) 
      {
        $dbval = $database[$idx];

        $pos = strpos($dbval, $subsets[$subIdx]);
        if ($pos !== false)
          $occurrences[] = $idx;

      }
      $resultAry[$subIdx] = $occurrences;   
    }

    return $resultAry;
  }

  header("Content-type: text/plain");

  print "Database:\n";
  print_r($database); 
  print "\n"; 

  $sstr = "the dogs whisperer";
  $subsets = CreateSubsets($sstr);  

  print "Subsets:\n";
  print_r($subsets);
  print "\n"; 

  $results = SearchOccurrences($database, $subsets);

  print "Results:\n";
  print_r($results);    
  print "\n"; 

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($subsets); $i++) 
  {
    print "'$subsets[$i]' was found in:\n";
    foreach ($results[$i] as &$resVal) 
    {
      print "  --> $database[$resVal]\n";      
    } 
    print "\n"; 
  }
?>
```